# Can a basilisk attack any type of wizard?

Tags: harry-potter, basilisk

We know that the Basilisk could attack muggleborns but could a basilisk attack a half -or pureblood (by free will) and get the same results? Or does it has to be controlled if it were to attack any of those type of wizards?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're after. Are you asking if the basilisk can harm a pure-blood?

Comment: Ummm...the basilisk did not hate Muggleborns by nature. Voldemort did.

Comment: Why wouldn't a basilisk attack? Does it know how to do other stuff? Judging by the movies, it isn't well suited for a subtle diplomatic approach.

Comment: Man, Basilisk could harm even dead people (ghosts)..

Answer (score 13):

Basilisks are extremely dangerous to *everyone*, regardless of blood status.

> *The Basilisk is a brilliant green serpent that may reach up to fifty feet in length. The male has a scarlet plume upon its head. It has exceptionally venomous fangs but its most dangerous means of attack is the gaze of its large yellow eyes. **Anyone** looking directly into these will suffer instant death.*
>
> ...
>
> *However, **since Basilisks are uncontrollable except by Parselmouths, they are as dangerous to most Dark wizards as to anybody else,***
>
> <sub><sup>[Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them)</sup></sub>

Comment: They actually appear to be asking whether basilisks will harm non-Muggleborns of  their own accord.

Comment: @Adamant - Hmm. I've added the rest of the quote. They'll attack everyone.

Comment: They will even attack and kill Muggles, if given the opportunity.  It isn't like there's anything special about wizards (from the Basilisk perspective) - they're all human-shaped prey.

Answer (score 0):

The could harm anyone. Even if a pure blood or half blood looked the basilisk in the eye, they would still die. Pure bloods and half bloods can also be petrified because it doesn't matter what their blood status is. That's like saying only death eaters kill muggleborns. And that's not true. At the battle of Hogwarts, a lot of half bloods and pure bloods lost their lives. Including Fred Weasley.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! While this is likely true do you have any evidence to back up your claim?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a basilisk will attack a half-blood, as Diary Tom Riddle commanded it to attack Harry. Also, anyone seems to be vulnerable; even a ghost (Nearly Headless Nick) was affected by the basilisk's gaze.